# changing textview to text from Bundle.getExtra()

Tags: android, android-intent, textview, android-edittext

Next question.. haha ( I have a lot of them).

I want to change my textViews to the contents of the Bundle.getExtras();

I found this example on stackoverflow

```
final TextView textViewToChange = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.completeCurrentMod);
    textViewToChange.setText(
        "The new text that I'd like to display now that the user has pushed a button.");
```

however, when I put it in my application it is throwing errors.

> 07-26 20:38:50.993: E/AndroidRuntime(31862): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   07-26 20:38:50.993: E/AndroidRuntime(31862):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.smallchangebigloss/com.example.smallchangebigloss.Complete}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 07-26 20:38:50.993:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(31862):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2460)
>   07-26 20:38:50.993: E/AndroidRuntime(31862):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2521)
>   07-26 20:38:50.993: E/AndroidRuntime(31862):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162) 07-26
>   20:38:50.993: E/AndroidRuntime(31862):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1370)
>   07-26 20:38:50.993: E/AndroidRuntime(31862):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 07-26
>   20:38:50.993: E/AndroidRuntime(31862):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 07-26 20:38:50.993:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(31862):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5777) 07-26
>   20:38:50.993: E/AndroidRuntime(31862):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 07-26
>   20:38:50.993: E/AndroidRuntime(31862):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 07-26 20:38:50.993:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(31862):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
>   07-26 20:38:50.993: E/AndroidRuntime(31862):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850) 07-26
>   20:38:50.993: E/AndroidRuntime(31862):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 07-26 20:38:50.993:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(31862): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   07-26 20:38:50.993: E/AndroidRuntime(31862):  at
>   com.example.smallchangebigloss.Complete.onCreate(Complete.java:17)
>   07-26 20:38:50.993: E/AndroidRuntime(31862):  at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5165) 07-26
>   20:38:50.993: E/AndroidRuntime(31862):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1103)
>   07-26 20:38:50.993: E/AndroidRuntime(31862):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>   07-26 20:38:50.993: E/AndroidRuntime(31862):  ... 11 more 07-26
>   20:39:40.676: E/AndroidRuntime(32566): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 07-26
>   20:39:40.676: E/AndroidRuntime(32566): java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.smallchangebigloss/com.example.smallchangebigloss.Complete}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 07-26 20:39:40.676:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(32566):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2460)
>   07-26 20:39:40.676: E/AndroidRuntime(32566):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2521)
>   07-26 20:39:40.676: E/AndroidRuntime(32566):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162) 07-26
>   20:39:40.676: E/AndroidRuntime(32566):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1370)
>   07-26 20:39:40.676: E/AndroidRuntime(32566):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 07-26
>   20:39:40.676: E/AndroidRuntime(32566):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 07-26 20:39:40.676:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(32566):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5777) 07-26
>   20:39:40.676: E/AndroidRuntime(32566):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 07-26
>   20:39:40.676: E/AndroidRuntime(32566):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 07-26 20:39:40.676:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(32566):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
>   07-26 20:39:40.676: E/AndroidRuntime(32566):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850) 07-26
>   20:39:40.676: E/AndroidRuntime(32566):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 07-26 20:39:40.676:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(32566): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   07-26 20:39:40.676: E/AndroidRuntime(32566):  at
>   com.example.smallchangebigloss.Complete.onCreate(Complete.java:17)
>   07-26 20:39:40.676: E/AndroidRuntime(32566):  at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5165) 07-26
>   20:39:40.676: E/AndroidRuntime(32566):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1103)
>   07-26 20:39:40.676: E/AndroidRuntime(32566):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>   07-26 20:39:40.676: E/AndroidRuntime(32566):  ... 11 more 07-26
>   20:40:38.598: E/AndroidRuntime(586): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 07-26
>   20:40:38.598: E/AndroidRuntime(586): java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.smallchangebigloss/com.example.smallchangebigloss.Complete}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 07-26 20:40:38.598:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(586):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2460)
>   07-26 20:40:38.598: E/AndroidRuntime(586):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2521)
>   07-26 20:40:38.598: E/AndroidRuntime(586):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162) 07-26
>   20:40:38.598: E/AndroidRuntime(586):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1370)
>   07-26 20:40:38.598: E/AndroidRuntime(586):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 07-26
>   20:40:38.598: E/AndroidRuntime(586):  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 07-26 20:40:38.598:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(586):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5777) 07-26
>   20:40:38.598: E/AndroidRuntime(586):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 07-26
>   20:40:38.598: E/AndroidRuntime(586):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 07-26 20:40:38.598:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(586):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
>   07-26 20:40:38.598: E/AndroidRuntime(586):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850) 07-26
>   20:40:38.598: E/AndroidRuntime(586):  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 07-26 20:40:38.598:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(586): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 07-26
>   20:40:38.598: E/AndroidRuntime(586):  at
>   com.example.smallchangebigloss.Complete.onCreate(Complete.java:20)
>   07-26 20:40:38.598: E/AndroidRuntime(586):    at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5165) 07-26
>   20:40:38.598: E/AndroidRuntime(586):  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1103)
>   07-26 20:40:38.598: E/AndroidRuntime(586):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>   07-26 20:40:38.598: E/AndroidRuntime(586):    ... 11 more

It is failing on this class when I click next.

```
package com.example.smallchangebigloss;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class GoalWeight extends Activity {

    private EditText edit;
    private String name,current;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_goal_weight);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        name = extras.getString("name");
        current = extras.getString("current");




        edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.currentWeightEdit);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.goal_weight, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void next(View view) {
        if (edit.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Ut Oh!")
                    .setMessage("Please enter your Goal Weight.")
                    .setNeutralButton("Try again", null).show();
        }
        else {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Complete.class);
            i.putExtra("goal", edit.getText().toString());
            i.putExtra("current", current);
            i.putExtra("name", name);


            startActivity(i);

        }
    }

}
```

and this is the next class:

```
package com.example.smallchangebigloss;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Complete extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        final TextView textViewToChange = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.completeCurrentMod);
        textViewToChange.setText(
            "The new text that I'd like to display now that the user has pushed a button.");
        System.out.println("name: " + extras.getString("name") + "Current weight: "
                + extras.getString("current") + "goal: " + extras.getString("goal"));

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.complete, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't called `setContentView()` yet so your `TextView` is `null`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

   // You need to call setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_file)
    final TextView textViewToChange = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.completeCurrentMod);
    textViewToChange.setText(
        "The new text that I'd like to display now that the user has pushed a button.");
```

If you try to initialize your `View` before inflating the `layout` it is contained in either with a `LayoutInflater` or by calling `setContentView()` your `View` will be `null` hence a `NPE` when you try to call a method on it such as `setText()`